# How to pull week to date data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to pull week to date data for a recurring report that needs to go out daily. For eg: report that goes out Monday needs to have data for Monday, report that goes out Tuesday will have data for Monday and Tuesday etc. for the current week.

I know how to pull last X days data with :

```
my_date > DATEADD(day, -6, GETDATE())
```

How do I pull only week to date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below SQL code in where condition:

```
where
my_date > DATEADD(dd, -((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, mydate) + 5) % 7), DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Comment: Thank you! This does not return anything when I use it. Can you explain what this is doing? I really appreciate the reply

Comment: Here is the explanation:
1st parameter: dd meaning day part.. 
2nd parameter: -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())-2) This returns the day of the week, - 2 because in sql week starts from sunday (-2 will set it to monday) and -ve  over all because we need to substract it.
3rd parameter: DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0), which return current date with time value set to 00.00.00.

To validate try this :
SELECT DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())-2), DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0))

Comment: @curiosav, I think you are not getting any records because either you don't have any data for this week since Monday or my_date field is not in sql DATE format.

Comment: I do have data for the week. What if i use - 
 SET DATEFIRST 1;
and then:
where my_date >= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) 
AND my_date <  dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
??

Comment: Thanks for helping out. your query makes total sense im just not able to figure out why its not returning records. the query i have written above works and returns data for the current week. I THINK that should work for my purpose...

Answer (score 0):

The correct adjustment requires a bit of extra modular arithmetic and so the proper number of days to adjust backward works out to the expression below. I am also assuming that `datefirst` is set to Sunday:

```
-((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, mydate) + 5) % 7)
```

If you just subtract two from the day number given by `datepart()` then you'll end up with a negative number on Sundays which then cause `dateadd()` to jump forward. You can see a listing of dates and comparison here:

https://rextester.com/IUY88999

Comment: very well noticed! I have updated the response as per your suggestion.